# Handlebars with Jammit and Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, jammit

I am trying to get Handlebars to work with Jammit and Rails 2.3... and I am struggling. I read different comments on how to make it work. For instance here:
https://gist.github.com/1118201
the last comment seems to imply that simply adding
   
  `template_function: Handlebars.template` 
in your assets.yml should work, but it does not for me. When I do :
     `JST[template_id](params)`
I get an javascript error:
     `TypeError: Object function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) { helpers = helpers || Handlebars.helpers; return "div class='timeline_container'\n/div    \n"; } has no method 'match'`

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!
PJ

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... hopefully it will help others.

It does work with the "compile" method included in Handlebars. You just need to add:
template_function: Handlebars.compile
at the top of your assets.yml file. No need for an extra script (Handlebars 1.0 rc.1).